# How to CENTER a Vertical Menu for ALL Screen Resolutions?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

**Does anyone know how to center a vertical drop down menu for all screen resolutions?**

I've tried literally **everything.** Either it will be too far left, too far right or move up and down the longer the screen resolution height is.

Menu Issue: http://www.differentregard.com/home.php

**CSS Code**: http://www.differentregard.com/css/homebg.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pure-CSS way to center something both horizontally and vertically I know of requires the thing to be of a fixed width and height, but given that:

- Position it absolutely, and set `left` and `top` to `50%`.
- Set left margins to negative half of the width and height respectively. (If you use borders or padding, you must account for that by adding them to the width/height before halving)

Comment: Thank you icktoofay. I don't understand about the left-margins. Do it like this? #nav { position: absolute; width: 280px; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 1; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif; color: #fff; list-style-type: none; } The only padding I have is the next line: #nav .main { padding-bottom: 20px; display: block; }

Comment: @80sBaby: You've got the absolute positioning right, but you don't have any margins there. [Here's a full demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/5p6sm/)

Answer (score 1):

Set width and give margin: auto;

```
example{
width: 150px;
margin: auto;
}
```

jquery

```
var a = $(window).height() / 2;
var s = $("#di").height() / 2;
$("#di").css("margin-top", a - s)
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3eCE/2/)

Comment: That centers it horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: Also, you might want to make sure that you change the margins on window resize, as well.

Comment: Yes, it's vertically centered when it's initially loaded, but sometimes people resize their browser window after the page has loaded, so you'll want to also set `margin-top` on resize.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it works for you

```
#logo{
```

position: absolute;

top: 22%;

width:100%;

height: 66px;

text-align:center;
}

#nav{

width: 100%;

text-align:center;

position: absolute;

top: 40%;

z-index: 1;

text-decoration: none;

text-transform: uppercase;

font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;

color: white;

list-style-type: none;}